# Why @drawable/logo won't resize?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to make the @drawable/logo image in my layout.xml bigger but no matter what I set the height and width attributes to it remains the same any help would be really appreciated

I've tried changing various different values in what to me seem relevant places to no avail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/imageView10" android:background="@drawable/bg2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@id/img_logo" android:background="@drawable/logo" android:layout_width="160.0dip" android:layout_height="160.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="20.0dip" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20.0dip" />
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/scroll_hr_ct" android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="15.0dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/btn_tv_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_tv" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="200.0dip" android:text="Button 1" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:alpha="0.8" />
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:id="@id/btn_epg_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_epg" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="200.0dip" android:text="Button 5" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:alpha="0.8" />
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/btn_movies_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_movies" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="200.0dip" android:text="Button 2" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:alpha="0.8" />
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/btn_series_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_series" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="200.0dip" android:text="Button 2" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:alpha="0.8" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/layout_footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80.0dip">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/imageView13" android:background="@drawable/black_bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:alpha="0.3" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="25.0dip">
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:id="@id/btn_vod_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_vod" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="60.0dip" android:layout_height="60.0dip" android:text="Button 5" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:id="@id/btn_radio_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_radio" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="60.0dip" android:layout_height="60.0dip" android:text="Button 5" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
            <ImageButton android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_gravity="center|right" android:id="@id/btn_settings_ct" android:background="@drawable/btn_settings" android:padding="10.0dip" android:layout_width="60.0dip" android:layout_height="60.0dip" android:text="Button 5" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@id/color_border" android:background="@drawable/border_color" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="5.0dip" android:alpha="0.0" />
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/img_foolter_logo" android:background="@drawable/developed_by" android:layout_width="162.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" />
        <TextView android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="bottom|center" android:id="@id/txt_version" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip" android:text="XCIPTV" android:alpha="0.0" />
        <TextView android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/textView4" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="OTT SERVICE PROVIDER" android:lines="3" android:alpha="0.0" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

image stays the same size.

Comment: Try using `android:scaleType="center_inside"` see doc : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType
And of course using `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background set the

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

Comment: appreciated but no didn't make any difference

Comment: What is this layout placed in?
Your frame layout has
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
Is it placed in a small parent?

Comment: its actually a premade iptv app that im trying enlarge the logo for, i presumed fill_parent would just mean the tv screen. crude working would be just to make another background and point it to that which would work im just trying to learn something really

Comment: it depends what the frameLayout is set in. If it is a fragment/activity that fills the parent then yes, otherwise it will only fill the space given.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the `scaleType` attribute on the `ImageView`. Add this to your ImageView in xml:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType).

Also check out this nifty guide to have a [visual understanding](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide).